# How to subset rows based on specific values from all columns

Tags: r

A sample dataset

```
v1 v2 v3 v4
1 CC DD EE
2 CC PP RR
3 EE QQ LL
4 OO RR EE
5 UU EE DD
```

I need to retain only rows that columns have DD **and** EE

```
v1 v2 v3 v4
1 CC DD EE
5 UU EE DD
```

Im trying with `df %>% filter_all(any_vars(. %in% c('DD', 'EE', 'bla bla')))` but this is not considering the **AND** condition

```
   v1 v2 v3 v4
    1 CC DD EE
    5 UU EE DD
```

Comment: If you only have two strings to check, two rowSums will do: `d[rowSums(d == "DD") & rowSums(d == "EE"), ]`, where all non-zero & non-zero will be `TRUE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a base R option using `rowSums`

```
> df[rowSums(sapply(c("DD", "EE"), function(x) rowSums(df == x) > 0)) > 1, ]
  v1 v2 v3 v4
1  1 CC DD EE
5  5 UU EE DD
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(v1 = 1:5, v2 = c("CC", "CC", "EE", "OO", "UU"), 
    v3 = c("DD", "PP", "QQ", "RR", "EE"), v4 = c("EE", "RR",
    "LL", "EE", "DD")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-5L))
```

Comment: actually im getting no results at all

Comment: @thelatemail Thanks for correcting me. See my update

Comment: what is the purpose of the "greater than 1" statement on `df[rowSums(sapply(c("DD", "EE"), function(x) rowSums(df == x) > 0)) > 1, ]`  ?

Comment: @AndresMora Since you have two criteria here, `>1` means both criteria are satisfied.

Comment: Can i have more than 2 criterias? Do i need to change the `>1` ?

Comment: @AndresMora If you have `N` criteria, then change `>1` by `==N` for easy understanding.

Comment: thanks. just a quick note after messing around with this approach for a while: it doesnt like NA's

Answer (score 2):

I guess this would work but it's not very concise:

```
library(tidyverse)
data <- tibble::tribble(~v1, ~v2, ~v3, ~v4,
                1, "CC", "DD", "EE",
                2, "CC", "PP", "RR",
                3, "EE", "QQ", "LL",
                4, "OO", "RR", "EE",
                5, "UU", "EE", "DD")
data %>% 
  filter(v2 %in% c("DD", "EE") & v3 %in% c("DD", "EE") |
         v3 %in% c("DD", "EE") & v4 %in% c("DD", "EE") |
         v2 %in% c("DD", "EE") & v4 %in% c("DD", "EE"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `if_any`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   filter(if_any(v2:v4, ~  . == 'DD') & if_any(v2:v4, ~ . == 'EE'))
#  v1 v2 v3 v4
#1  1 CC DD EE
#2  5 UU EE DD
```

---

Or if there are many values, then use `map/reduce`

```
library(purrr)
df %>% 
  filter(map(c("DD", "EE"), function(x) if_any(v2:v4, ~ . == x)) %>% 
           reduce(`&`))
#   v1 v2 v3 v4
# 1  1 CC DD EE
#2  5 UU EE DD
```

---

Or `paste` the columns and then use `str_detect`

```
library(stringr)
df %>% 
     filter(str_detect(str_c(v2, v3, v4, sep=""), "DD.*EE|EE.*DD"))
#  v1 v2 v3 v4
#1  1 CC DD EE
#2  5 UU EE DD
```

Comment: thanks but this will be limited to specific columns, right?

Comment: @AndresMora Not clear about your comment.  The columns are specified in a range `v2:v4` in second soluiton and in first

Comment: im thinking for the future. df might have multiple number of columns or different names

Comment: @AndresMora yes, but then you could use that in a range right?

Comment: @AndresMora You can also specify with select_helpers like `everything()` or `matches` etc